# Login attempt failed

Tags: 6, authentication-authorization

My Drupal 6 site's login function stopped working all of a sudden, with no error other than "login attempt failed".

- No database table crash
- Cookie domain is not set
- Drupal runs in "single-site" mode, not "multi-site"

The copy of the site runs well on my local machine.
Do you have any advice?

Comment: did you migrate domain?

Comment: check your sites/default/settings.php file to make sure it is set up to go to the correct database

Comment: No, I don't move to other domain. Other data for database is shown normally, just the login function stops working. So I think the the database setting is OK.

Comment: Check the .htaccess file in Drupal root. It is a hidden file, and if it's lost, then login won't work.

Comment: The .htaccess file is OK.

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot debug your site remotely, with no access to server, and no data. Unless you can tell us what changed and what errors are in your server's, database's and Drupal's logs, we will not be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found the cause: The "pass" field in "users" table by some accident was set as 32 chars long, which is far less than required by phpass module (128 chars long).
I re-installed phpass to make the table change as required and fixed the problem.

Comment: Oh you fixed your problem already. I haven't met this problem before but how could your "users" table changed like that?